# project is running in the emulator, but logcat does not show any logs, it writes offline Android Studio Kotlin Logcat pixel [OFFLINE]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator, logcat

[image: this is what the logcat screen looks like]

at first, the project was not opening when my emulator was turned on, then I made some changes with the port settings, I don't know exactly what I did, but I tried a lot of things, now my project is running in the emulator, but on the logcat screen, errors such as println logs do not appear.